# Android Studio Device File Explorer manually manipulate sharedpreferences file?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to manually manipulate my sharedpreferences .xml file on my device. I'm able to open it and edit it with Device File Explorer, but I'm not able to write it back to the device.

It's seems that in earlier versions of Android Studio the Device File Explorer had a "push" and "pull" function, but they are no longer present.

Is it possible to write directly to the device?

Btw. My device is not rooted.

Comment: Right-click over the directory and choose "Upload" to write something in Device File Explorer.

Comment: That was simpel!.... spent the whole night trying all sorts of workarounds. Damn it!  Thanks!